# Integration Primavera with SAP

Tags: integration, sap-erp, primavera

I have a study about Primavera and also the other idea in my integration team. We want to explore more Primavera and SAP, cause both EAM software have a good function.

My question is, can we integration both software?

Comment: This is an overly broad question that does not fit into the format of StackOverflow, but Primavera has a Java Integration API that can help you: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16281_01/Technical_Documentation/Integration_API/ProgrammerReference.html

Comment: Primavera is Oracle software, but SAP is software company, I guess you are talking about modules PS/PPM in software SAP ERP (ECC or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can. Primavera api is Java based, so you would need Java knowledge. I don't know if they still distribute it but they used to have also sdk that you can use, which can be used by vb, c# etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Primavera API to integrate with SAP or any other EPC software.
Primavera API is very versatile.